# Function returning null in save post

Tags: wordpress

I have a function that returns an array for me to dynamically populate the names of inputs of a post type. So I have this array and make a loop to generate the inputs.

This function is returning the array normally in other places, but in function that I use save_post always returns NULL. So, I can not get the names to save the values ​​with update_post_meta.

Why this function returns NULL in the function that I use save_post and other returns values ​​normally?

Could anyone help?

Thanks ...

```
function retornaPresencas() {

        $post_id = $_GET['post'];
        if (is_null($post_id)) : 
            return;
        else:

            $datas_turma = array(); $presenca_to_check = array();
            $turma_da_lista = get_field("turma_lista", $post_id);

            $args = array( 'post_type' => "turmas", 'p' => $turma_da_lista );

            $query_turma_lista = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ($query_turma_lista->have_posts()) : while ($query_turma_lista->have_posts()) : $query_turma_lista->the_post();

            if(get_field('lista_de_dias_turma')) {
                while(has_sub_field('lista_de_dias_turma')) { 
                    $datas_turma[] = get_sub_field('dia_de_aula');
                }
            }

            $lenght_datas_turma = count($datas_turma);
            $alunos_turma = get_field('lista_de_alunos_turma');

            foreach ($alunos_turma as $single_aluno) :
                for ($i=0; $i < $lenght_datas_turma; $i++) :
                    $presenca_to_check[] = $single_aluno."_".$turma_da_lista."_".$datas_turma[$i];
                endfor;
            endforeach;

            endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();

        endif;

        return $presenca_to_check;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like variable scope. Can you add some code to your question?

Comment: The function returns my array normally excepts in save post function...

Answer (score 0):

Saving a post in wordpress is a `POST` rather than a `GET`. When you attach a function to the `save_post` action, it is passed an argument containing the post ID. Amend your function to use the provided argument when called from `save_post`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if/else statement and add $post_id as a function argument.

```
function retornaPresencas( $post_id ) {
    $datas_turma = array(); $presenca_to_check = array();
```

...